# Rational canonical form and inverse to verify

Tags: linear-algebra

Find rational canonical form R  of given 4×4 matrix
     (2 1 0 0)
     (0 2 0 0)
     (0 0 2 0)
     (0 0 0 2)
    And invertible matrix P such that P^1 AP=R